# What does /(slash) meant for, in CSS?

Tags: html, css, shortcut

For rendering a Oval with CSS styles, I found the below CSS rules in some website

```
#oval {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
     -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
          border-radius: 100px / 50px;
 }
```

But what does 100px / 50px means?

What is the meaning of **/(slash)**  in CSS? And Where and all we can use this shorthand notattion?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius. And you can use the slash wherever it's supported. Try reading the docs.

Answer (score 9):

> If values are given before and after the slash, then the values before the slash set the horizontal radius and the values after the slash set the vertical radius

— http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius

Answer (score 0):

It refers to Horizontal and vertical border radius and is used for edge radius that are not perfectly circular and are instead more elliptical.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

> Note: Firefox only supported elliptical borders in 3.5+ and older WebKit browsers (e.g. Safari 4) incorrectly treat "40px 10px" as the same as "40px/10px".